Quarkus Load multiple Configurations to create multiple Instance of the same Java-Configuration Class
I have a .properties file with the following example content:
test1.name=test1
test1.url=www.test.com

test2.name=test2
test2.url=www.test2.com

I want to map this to different instances of the same Java interface/class in Quarkus. Currently, I’ve found the following approach, which should work:
interface Generic {
  String name();
  String url();
}

@ConfigMapping(prefix = "test1")
interface Test1 extends Generic {}

@ConfigMapping(prefix = "test2")
interface Test2 extends Generic {}

However, since I need several instances of this class based on configurations, I wanted to ask if there’s a smarter way to achieve this (without so many interfaces). Here a Spring Boot inspired example:
@Dependent
class Configuration {

  @Produces
  @Name("test1")
  Generic test1(@ConfigMapping(prefix="test1") Generic test1) {
    return test1;
  }

  @Produces
  @Name("test2")
  Generic test2(@ConfigMapping(prefix="test2") Generic test2) {
    return test2;
  }
}

I would also be very interested in other solutions to this type of problem.
Thanks in advance!

You can override the prefix on injection point as:
@Inject
@ConfigMapping // uses the one set in the interface
Generic generic

@Inject
@ConfigMapping(prefix = "override")
Generic genericOverride


Wow, that's even easier than I had hoped. Thanks for the quick reply. I'll check it out later and then confirm here if it works as expected
